# SAS Enterprise Guide - How can I download a ZIP file from a website, extract its contents and run it?

Tags: sas, zip, enterprise, unpack, enterprise-guide

I would like to have a task to download a continuously updated .ZIP data file from a specific website, extract its contents and run the file inside.

I am looking for a program code that performs these tasks and, so to speak, if the data on the website is updated, then my data file is also updated with it.

How can I do it?

Please help!
SAS Enterprise Guide 8.2

I didn't find a solution for it.

Comment: You can use `Proc HTTP` or `Proc S3` or FILENAME access method `FTP` or `SFTP` to download a file.  A zip file is read using the FILENAME ZIP access method.

Answer (score 1):

Read Chris method here for reading a zip file using filename statement: https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2014/01/29/using-filename-zip/

Chris is the community director at SAS (something like that). A zip file will be locked on an update. Check the file date and store the date somewhere so you can see if it changed.

There are lots of ways to approach your problem and I dont know your constraints. Start with Chris' post and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could download the zip using `proc http`

This macro will let you unzip it: https://core.sasjs.io/mp__unzip_8sas.html

And this macro will give you the recursive directory contents: https://core.sasjs.io/mp__tree_8sas.html